# netsh dhcp binding command not working on Server 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2016, netsh

I have kind of a weird issue.

I'm migrating Server 2008 R2 to Server 2016.

We have a DHCP Server role which services two scopes.  When setting them up, a line runs:

```
netsh dhcp server \\computername set bindings "ethernet1" enable
```

On Server 2016, I get:

> DHCP Server Set Bindings failed.  Parameter(s) passed are either
>   incomplete or invalid

On Server 2008 R2, the same command runs successfully.

I don't think my DHCP Server is setup improperly, because if I go into a cmd prompt, type `netsh dhcp server`, which puts me in netsh, then type `set bindings "ethernet1" enable`, it works.  So it makes me think it's the server name that it does not like, but `netsh dhcp show server` shows:

2 servers found in the directory service:

```
  Server [computername.domain.com] Address [xxxxxxxxxxxx]
  Server [computername.domain.com] Address [yyyyyyyyyyyy]
```

Any idea what I'm getting wrong? I can't find any way to get some more useful information from `netsh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has been deprecating the `NETSH` cmd for years. I'm a little surprised to see that it is still present in Server 2016. Have you tried using the Powershell cmdLets?

```
Set-DhcpServerv4Binding -BindingState $True -InterfaceAlias "Wired Ethernet Connection"
```

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/dhcpserver/dhcpserver
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/dhcpserver/set-dhcpserverv4binding

Comment: Yeah there is a message about depracating netsh dhcp, I'm just trying to change as little as possible.  I'll use a cmdlet, thanks.